# Return middleware from middleware

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am using [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) and would like to have different checks based on a value in the request body.

I have created a function for this, but I am not getting any responses back (i.e. express just hangs.):

**validation/profile.js**

```
module.exports = function (req,res,next) {
    if (req.body.type == 'teacher') {
        return check('name').exists().withMessage('Name is required'),
    } else {
        return check('student_id').exists().withMessage('Student id is required'),
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
router.put('/', require('./validation/profile'), (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req).formatWith(errorFormatter)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped() })
    } else {
        res.send(req.user)
    }  
})
```

If however, I write my function as a normal function (not as [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) with 3 params) and call it, it all works. But this way, I won't have access to the request object. I have to "hard-code" the params.

**validation/profile.js**

```
module.exports = function (type) {
    if (type == 'teacher') {
        return check('name').exists().withMessage('Name is required'),
    } else {
        return check('student_id').exists().withMessage('Student id is required'),
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
router.put('/', require('./validation/profile')('teacher'), (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req).formatWith(errorFormatter)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped() })
    } else {
        res.send(req.user)
    }  
})
```

Any suggestions on how could I achieve having different checks based on a value in the request body?

Comment: `require('./validation/profile')('teacher')` needs to return a middleware function in order to work properly.  The way you have it, you're executing it once only when your code first initializes.  There is no middleware in play there at all.

Comment: When I look at the `express-validator` doc, it doesn't appear like you're using `check()` right at all.  `check()` itself returns middleware.  You need to be using it that way.  I will delete my answer since your question is so far off it is  misleading.

Answer (score 2):

The `express-validator` [check API](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html) creates the middleware, you should attach it to express directly or call it yourself as express would.

```
// Use routers so multiple checks can be attached to them.

const teacherChecks = express.Router();
teacherChecks.use(check('name').exists().withMessage('Name is required'));

const studentChecks = express.Router();
studentChecks .use(check('student_id').exists().withMessage('Student id is required'));

module.exports = function (req,res,next) {
    if (req.body.type == 'teacher') {
        teacherChecks(req, res, next);
    } else {
        studentChecks(req, res, next);
    }
}
```

You could also potentially use [`oneOf`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html#oneofvalidationchains-message) to do the same thing.

```
router.put('/', oneOf([
    check('name').exists().withMessage('Name is required'),
    check('student_id').exists().withMessage('Student id is required')
], 'Invalid request body'), (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req).formatWith(errorFormatter)
    if (
        !errors.isEmpty()
    ) {
        return res.status(422).json({errors: errors.mapped()})
    }
    else {
        res.send(req.user)
    }
});
```

Comment: Both of them great work, thanks! I just have one more question: What if I would like to have more than one check per type? How could I accomplish that using the first method?

Comment: You can create additional routers and attach the checks to them, I have updated my answer with a solution.